# Enable Networking On Trusty Server

Tags: networking, server

I've just done a clean install of Trusty Tahr on one computer and transferred the drive to my actual server (I'm using an old laptop for my server, as it wouldn't/couldn't install and kept dropping to initramfs). I've been having issues with connecting to my network, and I thought the problem was with the hardware, so I tried this:

```
lshm -c network
```

Which revealed this:

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: p5p1
   version: c1
   serial: 60:eb:69:94:c0:95
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: (snipped for brevity)
   configuration: (snipped for brevity)
   resources: irq:17 memory:d3400000-d343ffff
```

How do I 'enable' this adapter?

Comment: sudo ifup -a returns:
cannot find device "eth0"
error getting hardware address for "eth0": no such device
failed to bring up eth0

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

(I'm guessing that) since I installed the OS on a different computer than the one it is currently in, the system was configured to use that computers' hardware as the default for 'eth0' (and I can't wait to see what other issues this will cause...)

The solution I used is:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Delete this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And replace with this:

```
auto (logical name)

iface (logical name) inet dhcp
```

Next type:

```
sudo ifup -a
```

Verify the fix:

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

if it no longer says 'disabled' by *- network, then it should be working

Finally, test the fix (I needed to update anyway)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install (whatever packages you want)
```

If anyone can tell me how I can configure the logical hardware ID's to the defaults Ubuntu uses, I'd be ever grateful!

Comment: I neglected to mention to save the changes in the vi editor, you will need to hit the esc key, then press shift+: (colon), type w to save; to exit press shift+: and type q

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I have found on [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1505697.html). Download the file named "[compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2](http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2)". Save it to your desktop. Then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install build-essential

cd ~/Desktop

tar -xjvf compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2

cd compat-wireless*

scripts/driver-select atl1c

make

sudo make install
```

Reboot. Test your ethernet connection which should work automatically after reboot. If not, run:

```
sudo modprobe atl1c
```

For the wireless to work too you can install additional packages by running:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
echo wl | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Use the NetworkManager applet from system tray to connect your wireless devices too.